# TOC margin adjustment

Tags: tables, spacing, table-of-contents

I would like to remove any space between margin and table names in LOT. Is there any command for adjusting this space?.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question. So I do not know which package is used to format the LOT.

Maybe it is package **`tocloft`**. Then you can redefine `\cfttabindent`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\renewcommand\cfttabindent{0pt}% <- 
\renewcommand\cfttabnumwidth{5em}
\renewcommand\cfttabpresnum{\tablename\ }
\renewcommand\cfttabaftersnum{:}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{First table}
\caption{Second table}
\caption{Third table}
\caption{Fourth table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Or it is **package `tocbasic`**. Then you have to set option `indent=0pt` for toc style entry `table`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\thetable{\Roman{table}}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  indent=0pt,% <- 
  dynnumwidth,
  entrynumberformat=\entryprefix{\tablename}
]{tocline}{table}
\newcommand*\entryprefix[2]{#1\ #2:\hfill}

\begin{document}
\listoftables
\begin{table}[htb]
\caption{First table}
\caption{Second table}
\caption{Third table}
\caption{Fourth table}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Run three times to get

[image]

Or it is a different package ...

Without any package you can redefine `\l@table`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\l@table{\@dottedtocline{1}{0pt}{2.3em}}
\makeatother
```

The second argument of `\@dottedtocline` is the indention of the entry number and the third argument is the horizontal space reserved for the entry number.